# Lose the value of $_SESSION[] when redirect

Tags: php, session

i have a problem, can't understund anyway.

i have three files - `index.php`, `admin.php`, `post.php`

in `index.php` i have

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['login11_error'] = 'yes';
if(verifying username and password here, if they correct)
{
     $_SESSION['login11_error'] = 'no';
     header('Location: admin.php');
}
?>
```

in `admin.php` i have

```
<?
session_start();
<form action="post.php" method="post">
...
?>
```

and finaly in `post.php`

```
<?
session_start();
some functions here...
header("location:admin.php");
?>
```

---

but when it redirected to `admin.php` from `post.php` it lose the value of `$_SESSION['login11_error']`.

any ideas?

Thanks...

UPDATE

fixed.

because i just show the structure of script here, i have a mistake in my question.

post php is in another folder, then index.php and admin.php, it's in `/folder1/folder1_1/post.php`

in post.php i was writing `header('Location: http://bs.am/admin.php")`

and when i change it to `header('Location: ../../admin.php")` it start working.

incomprehensible behavior for me, but works:)

Comment: How is the session ID passed along?

Comment: @Gumbo sorry? don't understand... what ID?

Comment: when i print the value of `$_SESSION[login11_error]` in `post.php`, it shows normaly, so i can't understund what is the problem.

Comment: These files don't really mean anything in their current state. What actions are taking place? From what I see, the only SESSION variable being set is in index.php... Your structure confuses the hell out of me. Why does index.php redirect to admin.php when admin.php has the form? And what use is post.php at all? It seems to me like index.php should be post.php instead.

Comment: @Syom: The session ID identifies the session. When `session_start` is called, it looks for a valid session ID passed along the request with the name specified in *session.name* (default is *PHPSESSID*). If none is found, it generate a new one for the current session. This session ID is then used to identify the session by sending it along with any subsequent requests. It is either passed using a cookie or by appending it to the URL as a parameter.

In your case you need to check if that session ID is the same for the subsequent requests.

Comment: @animuson i just show the stucture.

in index.php i make registration, if username and password are correct, i set the session variable to **no** and redirect to admin.php. there i verify, if **session = no**, i continue the script, but if no, i redirect it back to index.php. This is for security. And finaly post.php is for writing data to database...

Comment: @Gumbo how can i verify the session ID?

Comment: @Syom: You don’t need to do that; `session_start` is doing all the work for you. But you can get the current used session ID by calling `session_id`.

Comment: Hint: Instead of `'yes'` and `'no'` you may want to use `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in post.php i was writing header('Location: http://bs.am/admin.php")

and when i change it to header('Location: ../../admin.php") it start working.

incomprehensible behavior for me, but works:)

Answer (score 2):

Syom,

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your sample code.

If the redirect from index.php to admin.php works (persists your session variable), then there must be something screwy happening in post.php. Can you comment out all of your code in post.php and simply redirect to admin.php? That is, post.php would only contain:

```
<?
header('Location: admin.php');
?>
```

If `echo $_SESSION['login11_error'];` (in admin.php, after your start_session() of course) prints something, start uncommenting items in post.php.

If you're at a stand still, copy the example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php and make sure it works for you.

Comment: i try to delete all data from `post.php`. and what is strange - i have the variable correct in post.php(i try to print it there), but when it redirect to admin.php, it deletes it's value...

Comment: Syom,

There must be something going on in post.php, because the redirect logic used in index.php (header('Location: admin.php');) works (right?).

Comment: i fixe it, see the update. but very strange behavior i think. why i can't write the whole url in header?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `session_name('MySESS');` manually before every `session_start()`