# php $_SESSION empty when redirecting to different folder

Tags: php, session

I've been facing this problem for 6 hours now.

To make it simple, I have created some code to emulate the problem I have.

Say, I have the following file structure:

- path/

  - folderA/
  - test_sessionA.php
  - folderB/

    - test_sessionB.php

test_sessionB.php:

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'session';
header('Location: ../test_sessionA.php');
```

test_sessionA.php:

```
<?php session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```

With the above structure test_sessionA.php will output empty array. But if I move test_sessionA.php to the same folder with test_sessionB.php it will output the correct value.

Do you guys have found solution for this issue?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Tried the following without success:

- add `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/')` before starting session
- redirect with absolute url `header('Location: http://domain.org/path/test_sessionA.php')`

Could it be something wrong with server configuration because these codes runs well on my local machine. PHP versions are 5.3.8 (local) and 5.2.17 (hosting).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175939/lose-the-value-of-session-when-redirect?rq=1

Comment: You should be handling session starting/stopping from a common configuration file.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using a relative link to redirect? `../test_sessionA.php` vs `http://mysite.com/test_sessionA.php`

Comment: Try to put `session_set_cookie_params(0, "/");` before both `session_start();`

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your session.cookie_path is misconfigured. You can change it in your php.ini or try to set it using `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/')` before you start your session.